# Php to use value of a variable from 1st function to 2nd function

Tags: php, mysql, calculation

I have 2 functions working successfully but unable to find a way so that a value in function 1 as made of $r can be used in function 2 (there are many other functions like function 2 with slight modified calculations)'
so how to see that $r as fetched through function 1 is added in function 2 and others

```
if($NewCarVariantDetail){  
    $db = JFactory::getDBO();   
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query->select($db->qn(array('id','v_price','v_fuel_type','v_capacity')))
              ->from($db->qn('#__newprod_variants'))
               ->where([$db->qn('state') . ' = 1',
        $db->qn('id') . ' = ' . (int)$NewCarVariantDetail])
        ->order('v_price/2 asc','v_fuel_type desc');
              $db->setQuery($query);    
            $rows = $db->loadObject();
    $a = $rows->v_price;
    $b = $rows->v_fuel_type;
    $eng = $rows->v_capacity;

$z=.02034;
$p=.01809;
$q=.01779;
$qr=.01737;

$sma=7325;
$mid=11975;
$lar=27930;


if ($eng < 1000)
 {
     $r = (($z*$a)+$sma);
 }
else if((($eng >= 1000) and ($eng < 1500)))
 {
     $r = (($p*$a)+$mid);
 }
 
else if(($eng >= 1500) and ($a < 1900000))
 {
     $r = (($q*$a)+$lar);
 }

else if(($eng >= 1500) and ($a > 1900000))
 {
     $r = (($qr*$a)+$lar);
 } 
 

    
    $list='                                        
                <div class="common-box">
                    <div class="common-box-left">Basic Prem</div>
                    <div class="common-box-right">
                        <input name="voluntary_excess" type="text" class="text-box"  value="Rs. '.(round($r)) .'" readonly=""/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                ';  
    die($list);
}
```

*2nd Function where wish to use $r as fetched in 1st function*

```
if($RtoDetail){  
    $db = JFactory::getDBO();   
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query->select($db->qn(array('id','v_price','v_fuel_type','v_capacity')))
              ->from($db->qn('#__newprod_variants'))
               ->where([$db->qn('state') . ' = 1',
                $db->qn('id') . ' = ' . (int)$RtoDetail]);
              $db->setQuery($query);    
            $rows = $db->loadObject();
    $a = $rows->v_price;
    $b = trim($rows->v_fuel_type);
    $eng = $rows->v_capacity;
    $calculatedtax = '';

if (($a < 400000) && ($b == 'Petrol'))
                {           
                    $calculatedtax = (.04*$a);
                }
                            
else if((($a >= 400000) and ($a < 600000)) and ($b == 'Petrol'))
                {           
                    $calculatedtax = (.05*$a);
                    
                }   
                
else if((($a >= 600000) and ($a < 1000000)) and ($b == 'Petrol'))
                {           
                    $calculatedtax = (.07*$a);                  
                }

else if((($a >= 1000000)) and ($b == 'Petrol'))             
                {           
                    $calculatedtax = (.10*$a);
                    
                }   
    $list='         
                <h2><u> Fees </u></h2>                
                <div class="common-box">
                    <div class="common-box-left">Total Fee </div>
                    <div class="common-box-right">
                        <input name="roadtax" type="text" class="text-box"  value="Rs. '.(round($calculatedtax)) .'" readonly=""/>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="common-box">
                    <div class="common-box-left">Basic Prem</div>
                    <div class="common-box-right">
                        <input name="voluntary_excess" type="text" class="text-box"  value="Rs. '.(round($r)) .'" readonly=""/>
                    </div>
                </div>

                    
                                <div class="common-box">
                    <div class="common-box-left">Final Price </div>
                     <div class="common-box-right">
                    <input name="reg" type="text" class="text-box"  value="Rs. '.((round($a+ $calculatedtax + $r))) .'" readonly=""/>
                   
                    </div>
                </div>                                  
                ';  
    die($list);
}
```

Comment: You haven't shared any function definitions in your code. Also, is this problem really related to MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, don't repeat your-code, make it a function and call it wherever required, for example, `myFetchFunc(...)`.

After that, use caching technics inside said function.

But the "how and which" technic depends on how much you want to prevent repeating the query.

If repeating the query once per request is fine, use global variable/array as cache, like:

```php
<?php

function myFetchFunc($NewCarVariantDetail) {
    // Validate arguments.
    if ( ! $NewCarVariantDetail) {
        return NULL;
    }    

    // Load from cache (if called before).
    $uniqueKey = 'myFetchResult_variant-' . $NewCarVariantDetail;
    $cache = & $GLOBALS[$uniqueKey];
    if ($cache) {
        return $cache;
    }

    $db = JFactory::getDBO();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query->select($db->qn(array('id', 'v_price', 'v_fuel_type', 'v_capacity')))
        ->from($db->qn('#__newprod_variants'))
        ->where([$db->qn('state') . ' = 1',
            $db->qn('id') . ' = ' . (int) $NewCarVariantDetail])
        ->order('v_price/2 asc', 'v_fuel_type desc');
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $rows = $db->loadObject();
    $a = $rows->v_price;
    $b = $rows->v_fuel_type;
    $eng = $rows->v_capacity;

    $z = .02034;
    $p = .01809;
    $q = .01779;
    $qr = .01737;

    $sma = 7325;
    $mid = 11975;
    $lar = 27930;

    $r = 0; // Default value here.
    if ($eng < 1000) {
        $r = (($z * $a) + $sma);
    } else if ((($eng >= 1000) and ($eng < 1500))) {
        $r = (($p * $a) + $mid);
    } else if (($eng >= 1500) and ($a < 1900000)) {
        $r = (($q * $a) + $lar);
    } else if (($eng >= 1500) and ($a > 1900000)) {
        $r = (($qr * $a) + $lar);
    }

    // Save to cache.
    $cache = $r;
    return $r;
}
```

**Else**, there are a lot of caching libraries, which can store values longer than a single requests life-time.

Comment: Thanks, it looks promising but somehow getting error Notice: Undefined variable: r in F:\wamp64\www\14november2022\taxmodel.php on line 443

Comment: n yes query is raised once per request only.

Comment: If that line is inside `myFetchFunc`'s logic, then see edit (code needs a default value for `$r`, as none of the conditions may be met). Otherwise, if you remove duplicate logic, ensure to set `$r`, like `$r = myFetchFunc(...);`